# mysql Same day every year

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to use September 1st in a where clause and don't want to hard code the year.  Whats the best way to return 9/1/year to use in a between statement?

```
where p.post_date between '2016-09-01' and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Looking for a replacement of the '2016-09-01' so that it works again next year and going forward.  Also, needs to work for oct, nov and dec, of same year.

Comment: can you show us the `between statement`?  Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: where p.post_date between '2016-09-01' and  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Looking for a replacement of the '2016-09-01' so that it works again next year and going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want the previous year when you are before the turning date in the current year and the current one when you are after the turning date.

I would suggest to tell MySQL what date format you are using, to do so, you can use the `STR_TO_DATE` function.

```
CASE
  WHEN MONTH(CURDATE()) < 9 THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())-1, '-09-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
  ELSE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-09-01', '%Y-%m-%d'))
END
```

You can put this in a function/routine and use it wherever you need.

Comment: Thats it!  Thanks.  Final solution:

where p.post_date between 
CASE WHEN MONTH(CURDATE()) < 9 THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())-1,'-09','-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
ELSE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-09','-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')END 
and  DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `month()` and `day()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where month(datecol) = 9 and day(datecol) = 1;
```

Comment: How to use that in a between statement?

    where p.post_date between '2016-09-01' and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Comment: Using any kind of functions on a column will prevent MySQL to use indexes. Not a good idea.

Comment: @Pred . . . I don't see how to answer the question without a function on `datecol`.  I don't see what your answer has to do with the actual question, but the OP does and that is more important.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OP wanted a Year-To-Date calculation for a fiscal year, which is starting on the 1st of September. To be more precise the question was, how to get the starting date of the actual fiscal year.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want get the `year/09/01` of current year?

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable
 WHERE datecol = CONCAT ( YEAR(CURDATE()) , '/09/01')
```

Comment: Almost...sometimes it will be year minus 1 though. 

Like right now the reporting period is 2016/09/01 to today.  Next year the reporting period starts over on Sept. 1st.